# How to Debug Dotnet Backend + TSX Frontend?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, .net-core, jsx, react-tsx

My Problem:

I recently became the new Dev in a system which has a backend with Dotnet 3.1 and a Frontend of React, TypeScript and it is build with Yarn.

I can run the whole monster. For this, I first build the frontend, copy the created .js files to a static files folder in the backend, and run the Monster.dll.

How to debug the frontend? (I am afraid it relies on the backend being available.)

So far I tried to use Visual Studio but I'd try anything that is free and runs on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you confused the front-end environment with the back-end.

Basically, your React front-end application runs on browsers whereas dotnetCore application runs on CoreCLR. Meaning that you can debug your React front-end application in browser's Developer Tools in a basic way.

Ensure that the build operation of your React front-end app generates `source map` (*.map) files. These files map your browser compatible `js` output files to the `tsx` / `ts` sources. Then you should be able to debug it on your browser's Developer Tool.